# Creating split ellipse using tikz, arc

Tags: tikz-pgf, split, arc

I am trying to create an ellipse (split) using tikz and arc command.
[image]

Semi-major axis a = 5
Semi-minor axis b = 3

Coordinates of various points:
O(0,0);
A(4.797,0.846); B(0.526,2.983); C(-0.526,2.983); D(-4.797,0.846);
E(-4.797,0.846); F(-0.526,-2.983); G(0.526,-2.983); H(4.797,-0.846);

Angle made by OA with x-axis is 10 degree
Angle made by OB with x-axis is 80 degree
Angle made by OC with x-axis is 100 degree
Angle made by OD with x-axis is 170 degree
Angle made by OE with x-axis is 190 degree
Angle made by OF with x-axis is 260 degree
Angle made by OG with x-axis is 280 degree
Angle made by OH with x-axis is 350 degree

I have used the following and the result also attached.

> \begin{tikzpicture}
> \draw (4.797,0.846) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
> \draw (-0.526,2.983) arc(100:170:5cm and 3 cm);
> \end{tikzpicture}

[image]

Kindly suggest corrections to create correct split ellipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

May I suggest that you just mirror one ellipse with `scope`:
For the lines that became thicker i used `\edge`.

```
\documentclass[border=3.41mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    
    %axis
    \draw (0,-8) -- (0,8);
    \draw[] (-8,0)-- +(15,0) edge[thick] (8,0);
    
    % original ellipse
    \draw[thick] (4.797,0.846) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
    \node[xshift=5pt,yshift=-10](a) at (4.79,0.85) {A};
    \node[yshift=5pt,xshift=-10pt](b) at (0.75,3.28) {B};

    \draw[] (0,0)-- +(4.79,0.85) edge[thick] (8,1.45); % A line
    \draw[] (0,0)-- +(0.75,3.28) edge[thick] (1,4.5); % B line
    \draw[<->,>=stealth] (8,0) arc(0:28:2cm and 3 cm) node[midway,xshift=10pt]{10°};
    \draw[<->,>=stealth] (7,0) arc(0:80:7.25cm and 4.5 cm) node[midway,yshift=10pt]{80°};

    % mirror ellipse
    \begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
        \draw[thick] (4.797,0.846) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
        \node[xshift=-5pt](a) at (4.79,0.85) {D};
        \node[yshift=5pt](b) at (0.75,3.28) {C};
        \draw[] (4.79,0.85) -- (0,0);
        \draw[] (0.75,3.28) -- (0,0);
    \end{scope}

    % mirror ellipse
    \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=-1]
        \draw[thick] (4.797,0.846) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
        \node[xshift=-5pt](a) at (4.79,0.85) {E};
        \node[yshift=-5pt](b) at (0.75,3.28) {F};
        \draw[] (4.79,0.85) -- (0,0);
        \draw[] (0.75,3.28) -- (0,0);
    \end{scope}

    % mirror ellipse
    \begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]
        \draw[thick] (4.797,0.846) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
        \node[xshift=5pt](a) at (4.79,0.85) {G};
        \node[yshift=-5pt](b) at (0.75,3.28) {H};
        \draw[] (4.79,0.85) -- (0,0);
        \draw[] (0.75,3.28) -- (0,0);
    \end{scope}

    \node[xshift=7pt,yshift=-7pt](o) at (0,0) {O};
    
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, your solution works!

Comment: I recommend you use polar coordinates for all of your coordinates. For example, point A at `(4.79,0.85)` can be replaced with `(10:5 and 3)`.

Answer (score 0):

Following code generated required image. Thank you all. I now better appreciate the scope and scale commands.[image]

```
% original ellipse
\draw[line width=1.5pt] (10:5 and 3) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);

% mirror ellipse
\begin{scope}[yscale=1,xscale=-1]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (10:5 and 3) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
\end{scope}

% mirror ellipse
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=-1]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (10:5 and 3) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
\end{scope}

% mirror ellipse
\begin{scope}[yscale=-1,xscale=1]
    \draw[line width=1.5pt] (10:5 and 3) arc(10:80:5cm and 3 cm);
\end{scope}
```

Comment: `\draw[line width=1.5pt, delta angle=70, x radius=5, y radius=3] foreach \stAng in {10, 100, 190, 280} { (\stAng: 5 and 3) arc[start angle=\stAng] };`